# Invalidate cache in WAS-hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, was

I need to invalidate cache entries held by a [WAS-hosted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) WCF service.  The wrinkle is that the invalidation trigger comes from an external process.  I have considered the following approaches:

1. Use [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache) with timed cache entry expiration.  This won't work for me because changes to the cache's underlying data do not happen on a schedule and I must not ever return stale data.
2. Add an "administrative" `InvalidateCache()` method on my WCF service to invalidate the cache that could be invoked by the external process when appropriate.  This would be workable if the WCF service were not WAS-hosted.  In other words, if the app were idle and unloaded by WAS, invoking the `InvalidateCache()` method would unnecessarily activate it.  I looked for ways that I might query WAS for the state of the service and conditionally call `InvalidateCache()` only if the service were active, but I could find no such APIs for WAS.
3. Use a Windows named event as the mechanism for triggering cross-process cache invalidation.  I think the WCF service could be configured to listen for a named event and invalidate its own cache in response, but that seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution to a common problem.

Is there a better approach or something that would make one of the three approaches above workable?

Comment: `2. [...] invoking the InvalidateCache() method would unnecessarily activate it` - this one does not look too bad for me. Why wouldn't you go with it?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan The WCF service provides on-demand info about a server process on the same host.  If no users require info about the server process, I would like the WCF service to be unloaded so as not to use take up computing resources that could be used by the server process.

Comment: does cache work in scope of the same process as service or in separate one?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan The cache lifetime and cache entry invalidation are controlled by the server process which is separate from the WCF service.

Comment: @Don, in such case there's another approach: to create separate "administrative" WCF-service with InvalidateCache() method.